# Определить разницу во времени

Tags: android

Для получения времени применяю:

```
public String hhmmss(){
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss ", locale);
    String timevaluetime =  timeFormat.format(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
    return timevaluetime;
```

В момент1 получаю время `String timevaluetime1 = hhmmss();`
В момент2 получаю время `String timevaluetime2 = hhmmss()`;
Как определить разницу во времени (период времени) прошедший между моментом1 и моментом2.

Comment: [как получить разницу во времени](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте, не проверял. Походу дела написал.

```
mTextView.setText(getCalculatedTime());

public String getCalculatedTime(String timevaluetime1, String timevaluetime2 ){

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = format.parse(timevaluetime1 );
    Date date2 = format.parse(timevaluetime2 );
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    String str = String.valueOf(DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(difference, "HH:mm:ss"));

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Не проходит:format.parse(timevaluetime1 ); и format.parse(timevaluetime2 ); подчеркнуты красной чертой волнистой,DurationFormatUtils выделено красным шрифтом

Comment: Возьмите эти две строки в Try/Catch

Comment: ООО! Спасибо! А что можно сделать с выделением красным DurationFormatUtils.

Comment: Попробуйте так, DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(difference, "HH:mm:ss", true)

Comment: Не сработало, а как подключать в проект  класс DurationFormatUtils или класс Duration?

Comment: Ой извините, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: Попробую, благодарю!

Comment: Работает, благодарю!